# Windows Server Sync?

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-share, synchronization, xcopy

Looking to see if anyone has knowledge in this.

Currently I am trying to set up 2 windows 2012 servers, to synchronize the files in C:\Company\Record of each machine.

For example.
Machine A makes 06-08-2016.log, it gets pushed to Machine B.
And vice versa.

I've seen guides which if it's on A, it can be moved to B, but not the reverse.

I also want this as soon as a file is created on either machine. I was thinking something like XCopy or an active directory is what I'm looking for, but I do not have much Win Server experience, only Linux.

(It's also be nice if Machine A and Machine B can compare a file and keep the most recent version if transferring one to the other). Overall, not sure if I'll need a file repo in between these two, Machine C to get everything.

Comment: What you're looking for is DFSR.  Take a look at that and come back if you have any further questions.

Comment: @BlueCompute  Is it possible to have server a sync to server b and have server b sync to server a?  --- aka so the newest files are on BOTH systems? Having issues understanding this.

Comment: This is exactly what DFSR does.  It's a 'last write wins' system, so which ever file is updated most recently gets synced to the other servers.